# How can I request the user's location in API.ai?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm creating an agent using api.ai and using a PHP script as a webhook. [The documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#json) doesn't make it clear on how to do it, but I'm wanting to request permission to the user's coarse location so they won't have to provide their location for requests.

I've tried echo-ing the JSON they mention, and putting it in as a custom payload for the default welcome intent, but neither of those seem to prompt me for permission to use my location.

How do I ask a user for permission to get their location?

EDIT: If I set my PHP script to respond to `intent.welcome` with the following JSON:

```
{
    "data": {
        "google": {
            "expectUserResponse": true,
            "systemIntent": {
                "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
                "data": {
                    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
                    "optContext": "To provide an accurate experience, ",
                    "permissions": ["DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The app asks me "To provide an accurate experience, , I'll just need to get your street address from Google. Is that ok?"

However if I say "yes", then the app keeps asking things like "Sorry, could you say that again?", so I can't actually get it to do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new Intent with the Event set to `actions_intent_PERMISSION`. (See image below.)

When this Event is triggered, your webhook will be called with the JSON `originalRequest.data.device.location` field in the request body populated with the location information you've requested.

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's what was missing! I tried `actions.intent.PERMISSION`, but it told me the event name was invalid. I also didn't see it in the auto-complete, so I wasn't sure if it was valid or not. Thanks!